# Using bootstrap 3 glypicons with webjars and jsf2.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jsf-2.2, wildfly

I'm trying to make a simple page with bootstrap and glypicons in jsf 2.2. I've included webjar's bootstrap dependency (and opening the jar I can see the fonts file are present).

When deploying the app to wildfly, bootstrap css works correctly, but icons shown are horrible (like a default font or something). Looking at the network tab in the browser, I only see 404 errors:

```
http://localhost:8080/proto/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap/3.1.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404

http://localhost:8080/proto/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap/3.1.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404
```

I tried including the other dependency (bootstrap-glypicons) and I only get the 404 errors twice. What am I missing?

This is how I'm including boostrap, which works correctly for css:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

And this is how I'm using the css classes:

```
<button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `<link>` tag instead of `<h:outputStylesheet>`
eg.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

--- UPDATE

This happen because ResourceHandler in JSF add library value (webjars) to the end of URI as a parameter:
faces/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?ln=webjars

in bootstrap.min.css CSS there are such references to files:
url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),

so if you want to use `<h:outputStylesheet>` you can write own ResourceHander or you can edit `bootstrap.min.css` and fix paths to `glyphicons-halflings-regular.*` files

In my opinion is better to use standard html tag `<link>` instead of `<h:outputStylesheet>` because JSF component tree will be smaller and it act on performance. Inside `bootstrap.min.css` there is no EL so there is no need to use `<h:outputStylesheet>`

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why this works? jsf's way to include css and javascript is using the outputStylesheet and outputScript tags. Changing this to the standard html5 tags solved the problem here, and also for AngularJS not loading a .map file. Is it a restiction of jsf?

Comment: Please see update of my answer. I hope it explain enough

Answer (score 3):

Small update: webjars has JSF specific versions of several CSS libraries, in case of the bootstrap CSS the following will work just fine:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-jsf.css" />
```

Note the `-jsf` suffix.