# JSF Page and webjar embedded (Bootstrap css)

Tags: jsf-2, webjars

I try to use bootstrap css in my JSF Page and have problems referenciong it.
Followed a tutorial I did the following:

added Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

added reference in the JSF Page:

```
<h:outputStylesheet  library="webjars"
                       name="bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <h:outputStylesheet name="css/mystyles.css" />
```

When calling the page only my "mystyles.css" could be referenced. See source of the HTML Page:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/j2eetest4_war_exploded/javax.faces.resource/css/mystyles.css.xhtml" />
```

What could be the problem referencing the webjar ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using bootstrap 3 glypicons with webjars and jsf2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188965/using-bootstrap-3-glypicons-with-webjars-and-jsf2-2)

Comment: You might want to check out https://www.bootsfaces.net/